# Man with saucer shaped machine that may or may not been a time travel machine

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel, tv

What is name of (TV?) Movie (possibly british) from between 1970-1980's involving a man with saucer shaped machine that may or may not been a time travel machine?

I am trying to remember a film I saw about 30 or 35 years ago on TV in Australia.
I remember VERY little as I was around 10 years old or less at the time.

Here is a list of what I DO remember:

- it was science fiction.
- there was an odd/possibly eccentric man. Could have been from the future or another planet.
- the man had some kind of craft that (I think) was shaped like a small, one man flying saucer. It may or may not have been able to travel in time. I believe there was some green colouring or lighting effect associated with the craft.
- the man may have worn a wide brim hat.
  Sorry, that is all I've got to go on :( I do not recall any plot. It might have been a TV movie or a failed series pilot.
- I do not believe any alien/creature was involved. I think all the protagonists were human or at least human-like. The whole thing could have been made on a BBC budget.

Comment: If not for the saucer shape, I'd suspect Doctor Who. But from your name I'm guessing it's not.

Comment: Might be "the Flipside of Dominic Hind"?

Comment: @MarkBannister I am almost 99% certain you are correct. A quick google search revealed images which triggered memories of this show. Thanks.

Comment: @BlackDalek: You're welcome.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely "The Flipside of Dominic Hind". Verified by video clips on youtube.

Comment: Mark, you should enter your comment as an answer so it can be accepted (and you can get the reputation benefit)

Comment: @RossPresser: Good advice.  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As discussed in the comments this appears to be [The Flipside of Dominick Hide](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0082390), an episode in the BBC's [Play for Today](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Play_for_Today) series:

> Dominick Hide, a time traveller from the year 2130, is studying the London transport system of 1980. Time travellers are supposed to be observers, and are strictly forbidden to land their flying saucers. One time traveller who broke this rule accidentally killed a dog, changing history and causing many future people to disappear. Inspired by his Great Aunt Mavis, Dominick decides to find his great great grandfather. He begins to land in 1980, where his strange clothes and speech make him seem an eccentric oddball.

A sequel, [Another Flip for Dominick](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083566), was broadcast a couple of years after the original episode.